# How to create Scheduled Notifications with custom date with the Awesome Notifications

Tags: flutter, dart, notifications, uilocalnotification

I ask the user the date and time and save them in variables, but I want to use these variables to choose the time of the notification.

For example There is a Date choosen

```
//Format the date
String _selectedDate = DateFormat("d MMMM yyyy").format(DateTime.now());

//Pick date and give it a custom date
_selectedDate = DateFormat("d MMMM yyyy").format(pickerDate);
//Pickerdate is just a custom date and _selectedDate formats it
```

How can i make it so that the notification plays a day before the `_selectedDate`

This is the code for the Scheduled Notification:

```
  void _scheduleNotification() {
    DateTime selectedDate = DateFormat("d MMMM yyyy")
        .parse(_selectedDate)
        .add(Duration(seconds: 5));

    AwesomeNotifications().createNotification(
      content: NotificationContent(
        id: 10,
        channelKey: 'basic_channel',
        title: 'Scheduled Test',
        body: 'This is a scheduled notification',
      ),
      schedule: NotificationCalendar.fromDate(date: selectedDate),
    );
  }
```

Note: When i run the above Scheduled Notification code I get the following error:

```
D/Android: [Awesome Notifications]: Date is not more valid. (2023-06-03 17:59:34 UTC) (NotificationScheduler:200)
D/Android: [Awesome Notifications]: Scheduled removed (NotificationScheduler:246)
D/Android: [Awesome Notifications]: Notification schedule removed in 5ms (NotificationScheduler:255)
```

What I have tried:
The below code works but it is instant and is not what im aiming for

```
  void _scheduleNotification() async {
    await AwesomeNotifications().createNotification(
      content: NotificationContent(
        id: 1,
        channelKey: 'basic_channel',
        title: 'Scheduled Notification',
        body: 'This is a scheduled notification',
      ),
      schedule: NotificationCalendar(
        weekday: DateTime.monday,
        hour: 8,
        minute: 0,
        second: 0,
        millisecond: 0,
        allowWhileIdle: true,
      ),
    );
  }
```

Any idea or help is Greatly appreciated...thx in advance